# Using SSE for vector initialzation

Tags: c++, vector, sse

I am relative new to C++ (moved from Java for performance for my scientific app) and I know nothing about SSE. Still, I need to improve the very simple following code:

```
    int myMax=INT_MAX;
    int size=18000003;
    vector<int> nodeCost(size);

    /* init part */
    for (int k=0;k<size;k++){
     nodeCost[k]=myMax;
    }
```

I have measured the time for the initialization part and it takes 13ms which is way too big for my scientific app (the entire algorithm runs in 22ms which means that the initialization takes 1/2 of the total time). Keep in mind that the initialization part will be repeated multiple times for the same vector.

As you see the size of the vector is not divided by 4. Is there a way to accelerate the initialization with SSE? Can you suggest how? Do I need to use arrays or SSE can be used with vectors as well?

Please, since I need your help let's all avoid a) "how did you measure the time" or b) "premature optimization is the root of all evil" which are both reasonable for you to ask but a) the measured time is correct b) I agree with it but I have no other choice. I do not want to parallelize the code with OpenMP, so SSE is the only fallback.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I suspect, if you are using `g++ -O3 -msse2`, it will do that for you in the first place (althoug Kerrek's suggestion below is neat, and may help). Writing about 70MB of data will take some time on all machines - reasonable expectation on a modern machine is around 5-10GB/s. If we go by 8MB/s, you can write 104MB in 13ms, so I suspect you are not that far of.

Comment: It's worth noting that using SSE won't help much on the "fill" front, since it's limited by the memory bandwidth, not the CPU's ability to execute the instructions. It may help if you use `non-temporal` stores however.

Comment: @Mats is 5-10GB/s a typo?

Comment: @greatwolf: What do you think it should be? Sure, if you are filling to CACHE (by using small size), it will be MUCH faster, but as far as I know, there aren't many processors around that has more than a few megabytes of cache, so the remainder of 70MB will have to be flushed to "real memory".

Comment: Check out the [Intel manual](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf). Each type of extended instruction set (MMX, SSE{,2,3,4}, AVX) has some kind of "packed move" operations. E.g. AVX has `MOVAPD` that operates on 32 bytes at once; and `MOVNTDQ` does the same with a non-temporal hint.

Comment: Allocate some contiguous space first, then select an aligned address in it as an offset. Then use the area from the offset to use avx/sse intrinsics on it incrementing until you reach last few elements. Then continue non-sse from there. Im using that with 18 GB/s dotproduct.

Comment: Lo and behold, my GCC *already* emits `vmovdqa YMMWORD PTR [rax], ymm0` to do the filling, even without any stimulation.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, modern gcc/g++ is pretty good at giving you SSE/AVX instructions on processors that support it, without much effort. I don't know if it works, but there's a patch here that seems to be introducing non-temporal stores (which at least on SOME processors will give 30-50% improvement because cache is not used to store the data, which actually helps when filling LARGE sections of memory).
http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2007-06/msg00627.html

Comment: @MatsPetersson: That sounds like a good idea. Though non-temporal stores seem to come with additional concurrency restrictions because they don't obey strong ordering, I believe. It would be very situational.

Comment: why not use omp : #pragma omp for ?! this speed up initialization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the vector's constructor:

```
std::vector<int> nodeCost(size, myMax);
```

This will most likely use an optimized "memset"-type of implementation to fill the vector.

Also tell your compiler to generate architecture-specific code (e.g. `-march=native -O3` on GCC). On my x86_64 machine, this produces the following code for filling the vector:

```
L5:
    add     r8, 1                    ;; increment counter
    vmovdqa YMMWORD PTR [rax], ymm0  ;; magic, ymm contains the data, and eax...
    add     rax, 32                  ;; ... the "end" pointer for the vector
    cmp     r8, rdi                  ;; loop condition, rdi holds the total size
    jb      .L5
```

The `movdqa` instruction, size-prefixed for 256-bit operations, copies 32 bytes to memory at once; it is part of the AVX instruction set.

Comment: This won't make the code any faster. And the init part will be repeated multiple times after the vector creation

Comment: @AlexandrosE.: Later you can use `std::fill`.

Comment: std::fill already saves 3ms. So, we are down to 10.7. That is why I upvoted your comment and your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try `std::fill` first as already suggested, and then if that's still not fast enough you can go to SIMD if you really need to. Note that, depending on your CPU and memory sub-system, for large vectors such as this you may well hit your DRAM's maximum bandwidth and that could be the limiting factor. Anyway, here's a fairly simple SSE implementation:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

const __m128i vMyMax = _mm_set1_epi32(myMax);
int * const pNodeCost = &nodeCost[0];
for (k = 0; k < size - 3; k += 4)
{
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&pNodeCost[k], vMyMax);
}
for ( ; k < size; ++k)
{
    pNodeCost[k] = myMax;
}
```

This should work well on modern CPUs - for older CPUs you might need to handle the potential data misalignment better, i.e. use `_mm_store_si128` rather than `_mm_storeu_si128`. E.g.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

const __m128i vMyMax = _mm_set1_epi32(myMax);
int * const pNodeCost = &nodeCost[0];
for (k = 0; k < size && (((intptr_t)&pNodeCost[k] & 15ULL) != 0); ++k)
{                                              // initial scalar loop until we
    pNodeCost[k] = myMax;                      // hit 16 byte alignment
}
for ( ; k < size - 3; k += 4)                  // 16 byte aligned SIMD loop
{
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i *)&pNodeCost[k], vMyMax);
}
for ( ; k < size; ++k)                         // scalar loop to take care of any
{                                              // remaining elements at end of vector
    pNodeCost[k] = myMax;
}
```

Comment: I get this error: main.cc:82:47: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘__m128i* {aka __vector(2) long long int*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void _mm_storeu_si128(__m128i*, __m128i)’

Comment: @huseyin: it depends on what C++ compiler you are using - in general though it's not possible to specify alignment for STL types.

Comment: @Paul R. I use gcc (Ubunutu 12.04). Your answer is slightly faster (just 10.5 ms instead of 10.6 ms of std::fill). So, it is obvious YOU are the man. Still, I must accept Kerrek SB answer, for its simplicity. But thanks bro.

Comment: No problem - it may be that `std::fill` is pretty well optimised already or it may be that you are hitting your DRAM bandwidth bottleneck, but either way it looks like it's not going to get much faster.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension of the ideas in Mats Petersson's comment.

If you really care about this, you need to improve your referential locality. Plowing through 72 megabytes of initialization, only to come back later to overwrite it, is extremely unfriendly to the memory hierarchy.

I do not know how to do this in straight C++, since `std::vector` always initializes itself. But you might try (1) using `calloc` and `free` to allocate the memory; and (2) interpreting the elements of the array as "0 means `myMax` and `n` means `n-1`". (I am assuming "cost" is non-negative. Otherwise you need to adjust this scheme a bit. The point is to avoid the explicit initialization.)

On a Linux system, this can help because `calloc` of a sufficiently large block does not need to explicitly zero the memory, since pages acquired directly from the kernel are already zeroed. Better yet, they only get mapped and zeroed the first time you touch them, which is very cache-friendly.

(On my Ubuntu 13.04 system, Linux `calloc` is smart enough not to explicitly initialize. If yours is not, you might have to do an `mmap` of `/dev/zero` to use this approach...)

Yes, this does mean every access to the array will involve adding/subtracting 1. (Although not for operations like "min" or "max".) Main memory is pretty darn slow by comparison, and simple arithmetic like this can often happen in parallel with whatever else you are doing, so there is a decent chance this could give you a big performance win.

Of course whether this helps will be platform dependent.

Comment: Still, when I need to do the initialization again (for the second time), I still need to make everything zero, so this will not save me any time (and I added one subtraction per access).

Comment: @AlexandrosE: Well, you can play other tricks, like using the high bits of the value as a "generation number". Main memory is hundreds of times slower than registers, so the extra addition/subtraction/generation check is likely to be undetectable by comparison. (And initializing or re-initializing is guaranteed to hit main memory.)